# Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered

Tags: windows-7, sleep, display-driver

The Control Panel's Power Options settings will put my laptop to sleep and then hibernate.  This has been working for a year without a problem.  Now, when I wake up my laptop, the machine will power on and the attached monitors will power on but the monitors will show black.  The only option is to hold down the power button to power off the laptop.

The above behavior happens if I put the laptop to sleep manually or let it go to sleep via the Power Options settings.

I set the following in the Windows registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\DCI
Timeout = 60
```

My laptop behaves the same; however, with a black powered-on screen, I can hit `Control` + `Alt` + `Delete`, type in my password and finally the desktop will display on the monitor.  In Windows Event Viewer in the System log under Windows Logs, I see the following warning:

```
Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered.
```

I set the following in the Windows registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDriver
TdrDelay = 0
```

It had no impact.

I undocked my laptop, plugged in the power and removed the wireless mouse adapter.  The laptop is now running with only the hardware that it came with (i.e. just the laptop).  I get the same behavior except the laptop's screen is powered on and black instead of the now unattached monitors.

The Intel Driver Update Utility shows that all drivers are up to date.  I re-installed the graphics driver and the problem persists.

I ran the BIOS system diagnostics by holding down the Fn key during boot.  There were no hardware errors detected.

I thought about booting into Safe Mode and try sleeping from there.  Unfortunately, I didn't see a Start menu option to sleep or hibernate while in Safe Mode.

I ran `sfc /scannow` and this fixed a few errors but didn't resolve the problem.

I ran `chkdsk C: /F /X` and I am not sure if it fixed any disk errors.  In any case, the display driver problem persists.

Here is the configuration of my laptop:

- Dell Latitude E6430

  - BIOS version: A14 (12/27/2013)
- Intel Core i5-3340M (Ivy Bridge)
- Intel HD Graphics 4000

  - Driver Provider: Intel Corporation
  - Driver Date: 3/30/2015
  - Driver Version: 10.18.10.4176
  - Video BIOS version: 2158v12
- 16 GB of RAM
- 500 GB SSD SATA ([Samsung 840 EVO][2])

  - Firmware version: EXT0BB6Q
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)

Here's the complete information from Event Viewer.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="Display"/> 
      <EventID Qualifiers="0">4101</EventID> 
      <Level>3</Level> 
      <Task>0</Task> 
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-08-12T17:05:43.000000000Z"/> 
      <EventRecordID>1391953</EventRecordID> 
      <Channel>System</Channel> 
      <Computer>nreynold-lap.us.oracle.com</Computer> 
      <Security/> 
   </System>
   <EventData>
      <Data>igfx</Data> 
      <Data/> 
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: What is the error ID from Event Viewer? I'd recommend reinstalling the graphics driver. Something is probably corrupt.

Comment: Try reinstalling the graphics driver.

Comment: @DrZoo I added the Event Viewer information.  I don't see an error ID.  I see an EventID.

Comment: @Steven I forgot to mention that I did re-install the graphics driver.  I edited the question to include that detail.  Thanks for calling this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already tried re-installing the [latest Graphics Driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=JVC00&fileId=3465609412&osCode=W764&productCode=latitude-e6430&languageCode=EN&categoryId=VI) and it didn't solve the problem.  This time I uninstalled the Graphics Driver and let Windows install its default driver.  I then updated the driver via Windows Device Manager.  This gave me an Intel driver from 2012.  This driver completely removed the option to put the laptop to sleep.  I then installed the [latest Graphics Driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=JVC00&fileId=3465609412&osCode=W764&productCode=latitude-e6430&languageCode=EN&categoryId=VI) and now my laptop can sleep and recover from sleeping.  Note: I rebooted the machine at each step.